# Skip in the middle of a toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".square").toggle(
        function(){ $(this).animate({"width":"200px"}, 900); 
                  },

        function(){ $(this).animate({"width":"100px"}, 900); 
        } 
    ); 

    $(document).click(function() {
       $('.square').animate({ "width":"100px"}, 900);  
    });
})​
```

In this example,
1- The user click the square once (the first function of the toggle is executed).
2- The user then click the background another function is called
3- The user click back the square (and I suppose the second function of the toggle is called, that does the same that the num. 2 and that is why nothing happens in the first click.)

So I suppose in the num. 2 I should skip all the toggle function. I don't know how to do it

**How to skip all the toggle if only the first function is executed?**

(by the way I tried "stop().animate" and it doesn't work)

Here is the example working. You can make changes: http://jsfiddle.net/xngx9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6QYXF/1/)*

```
$(function(){
    $(".square").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var tgl = $(this).width() === 100 ?
        $(this).stop(1).animate({"width":"200px"}, 900):
        $(this).stop(1).animate({"width":"100px"}, 900);
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
      $('.square').stop(1).animate({ "width":"100px"}, 900);  
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your var, can you explain it?. On the other hand, why do you put (1) in the stop?

Comment: @Narcis the `var tgl` (var "toggle") is *pro-forme*, the code will work also without it, but if we remove it, it will throw us an JS error: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." The three lines after the `e.stopPropagation()` are a *Ternary Operator* that says: `[statement]?[do something if is true]:[do else if is false];` and youa can put all in one line! . The `.stop(1)` is like I used `.stop(true)`. That is to prevent animations queue build-ups, It's used to clear them. **Now tell me: does this helps or not? otherwise I'm gonna remove my answer.**

Comment: Yes it helps. Thank you Roko. I didn't know about the ternary operator. If I understand right this is like a conditional. The syntax is condition ? if the condition is right : if the condition is wrong; If that is true why to use var tgl? why not diretly: $(this).width() === 100 ?

Comment: Yes, you get it right. That's a conditional statement. As I said, you can do it, but if you like to see your code debugged than you'll specify the `var`. For example, remove from the demo link `var tgl =` and click on the button **JS Lint**. and you'll see the error in the console/popup.